# Flutter app deployment on iPhone device issue

Tags: ios, flutter, runner

I'm asking for help after having tried several things but with no success.

**1 - The problem**

I can't deploy my flutter app on a physical iPhone (automatically signed) even if everything is alright on an iOS emulator and on Android emulator and phisical device...

Error at build in Android studio on "run" : (EDITED)

```
> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode... Legacy build system
> detected, removing
> /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
> Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified
> development team in Xcode project: VU929CKC2Q Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                                     
>                                 59,3s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>         2021-11-29 13:07:45.010 xcodebuild[92092:2943731]    DVTAssertions: Warning in
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
>         Details:    (null) deviceType from 00008030-0008252C0185402E was NULL when -platform called.
>         Object:      <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7fafa1b7f0c0>
>         Method:      -platform
>         Thread:      <NSThread: 0x7faf9ef4f360>{number = 3, name = (null)}
>         Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
>         ** BUILD FAILED **
> 
> 
> Xcode's output: ↳
>         note: Using new build system
>         note: Building targets in parallel
>         note: Planning build
>         note: Analyzing workspace
>         note: Constructing build description
>         note: Build preparation complete
>         /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set
> to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
> to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
>         /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set
> to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
> to 14.5.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
>         error: Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
>         Cycle details:
>         → Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
>         ○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app'
> to
> '/Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner.app'
> 
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> 
> Error launching application on iPhone.
```

**2- What i've tried :**

- i tried

> open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

and in Xcode select file > workspace settings > "legacy build" mode (found on another stackoverflow thread)
but seems it does not change anything and in the Xcode note from android studio terminal it still tries to "move to new build mode" !?

- also did tried with

> open ios/Runner.xcodeproj

file > project settings > legacy build mode...
does not work neither...

I'm quite disappointed and as an android developer (and more recently a Flutter one) i don't really know about iOS side :s

Thanks for your help ! :)

Here is my whole podfile ::

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
#       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once I introduced a second target build. For me it was caused by mistakenly including the `info.plist` and `Runner-copy.app` in the Xcode Target Membership which creates a circular reference. The `*info.plist` and `*.app` should not be in any Target Membership.

This has nothing to do with Targets in the Podfile.

To create a second Xcode target, open the project in Xcode and duplicate the Runner Target. There's a small tutorial on creating Targets in Xcode here - https://andersongusmao.medium.com/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687.

Once you have done that you'll need to select the membership of each of the files in the project. Most should be members of both/all Targets. If you have a plist that is specific to one target (e.g. production keys for one and dev keys for another) they should only be members of the associated Target.

As stated above, the `*info.plist` and `*.app` should not be in any Target Membership.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer but i don't understand what i have to do to correct this ?
I really don't know about iOS but what is usefull for my Flutter devs...
do i have to change the .plist ? 
if so, how ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited the post with complete android studio output if it can help...

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.